# unbind a jQuery plugin when no destroy argument is given

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins, sidr

I'm using a plugin which is called [Sidr](http://www.berriart.com/sidr/) to create a Facebook like sidebar. It intialized with:

```
$('#menu_trigger').sidr({
    name: 'sidr-right',
    side: 'right'
});
```

Problem is, that I only want to have this effect at a specific viewport size. I know that many jQuery plugins come with a something like a `destroy` argument to unload the script. But this plugin does not.

Does anyone know how I could unbind this function off `#menu_trigger` when a specific browsersize is triggered.
Like:

```
enquire.register("screen and (max-width:560px)", {
  $('#menu_trigger').sidr({
    // unload, unbind
  });
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/bemimu/8/edit

You can use unbind and pass in the plugin reference to the selected elements, then check the window size in JavaScript. $.sidr('close', 'sidr-right');

JS:

```
function clickForSidr() {

var ww = document.body.clientWidth;

  if(ww < 560){

      if(sidrIsOpen){
        $.sidr('close', 'sidr-right');
      }else {
        $.sidr('open', 'sidr-right');
      }
        sidrIsOpen = !sidrIsOpen;
  }
};

var sidrIsOpen = false;

    $('.unbindme').on('click',function(){
     clickForSidr();
    });
```

MARKUP:

```
<div class="unbindme" >unbindme</div>
```

Comment: Oh sorry, let me add the window resize logic.

Comment: sorry but that does not seem to work for me. Could you use my OP classes and plugins that I might not build in a mistake.

Comment: Do you want the menu to be removed or something when the window resizes?

It might not be an unbinding issue if that is the case.

Comment: You might be able to add something along the lines of  

$.sidr('close', 'sidr-right'); 

to the 'unbind' block to close the open menu?

like...

  if(ww > 560){
      $.sidr('close', 'sidr-right'); 
      $('.unbindme').unbind($.plugin);
    } else {

Sorry not sure of the case at this point

Comment: it does not work, when I type `$('.thebutton').unbind($.sidr);` it does not change anything.

Comment: Do you want to close the sidebar that is created or do you want to make the button not work anymore?

Comment: thanks for replying. I want to stop the instance, depending on the screensize, but then reactive it on another point. One can say I want to stop the button click slides out the sidebar (not for any click handler in general, cause I have others attached to the button too)

Comment: Okay try this...

$('button').on('click',function(){
   $.sidr('open', 'sidr-right');
});

then use $('button').unbind('click'); inside the if statement instead.

Comment: thank you for your effort. As I mentioned I have another clickhandler attached to the button (which has nothing to do with sidr).. so when I'm unbinding the click inside the if, it will remove that click handler too. And thats what I dont want.

Comment: okay...  this might be silly but could you just have the if statement inside of clickForSidr, and not even try to unbind the event? I edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: I really appreciate the help and effort you put in this, but it does not work. I'm console logging the `var ww` to check if something is wrong, but even on `< 560` the slider opens if I press the button.

Comment: tbh__ I got it mate, your code was fine though. The problem was that because I needed to initialize the function `sidr();` it was attached once on document ready. I just had to remove the element then and it worked. I will mark this as answered, because your idea was fine though!

Comment: Ahhh.  It always something. Good to hear.